# SwiftUI minimumScaleFactor not working on Device

Tags: swiftui

I am relativly new to iOS dev and currently build a small app to display aviation weather (METARs).
The first thing I build was a widget view where the METAR, just text, is displayed.
Since the length of the text is changing depending on the weather I used the "minimumScaleFactor(0.01)" to resize the texts font size.

I then changed the text to a multi text block thing (?) because I wanted to highlight different text parts with color. The only way I got this working is with a reduce function:

```swift
metar.blocks.reduce(Text(""), { $0 +
            getMetarTextBlock(block: $1)
            + Text(" ")
        })
        .font(.custom("Menlo", size: 20))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
```

This way I got the dynamic resizing working too.

Next I moved to the app itself and not the widget. I reused the same view to display the colored text with dynamic size. But it only works in the XCode Preview and Simulator - not on my physical device (iPhone 12 pro MAX).
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If I replace MetarText(..) with Text(raw_metar) resizing works.
So my guess is its not playing well with this reduce method.

Text View:

```swift
struct MetarText: View {
    var metar: Metar
    var color: Color = .black
    init(metar: Metar) {
        self.metar = metar
    }
    var body: some View {
        metar.blocks.reduce(Text(""), { $0 +
            getMetarTextBlock(block: $1)
            + Text(" ")
        })
        .font(.custom("Menlo", size: 20))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
    }
}

func getMetarTextBlock(block: MetarBlock) -> Text {
    var color = Color.white
    switch(block.condition){
    case .IFR:
        color = Color.red
    case .SVFR:
        color = Color.blue
    default:
        color = Color.white
    }
    return Text(block.text)
        .foregroundStyle(color)
}
```

Usage:

```swift
HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text(item.station)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Spacer()
                    ConditionView(condition: item.condition)
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                    .padding(0)
                MetarText(metar: item)
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            Button(role: .destructive) {
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
            }
            .imageScale(.large)
            .frame(width: 80)
        }
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf4SG.png)
[Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0AB7.png)

I tried it on Preview, Simulator and device. I expected same behavior but on the device its different.
Latest iOS update is installed.

Comment: What happens if you add a `.lineLimit(2)` after the `.minimumScaleFactor(0.01)` in `MetarText`?

Comment: Option 2 to try out: add a `.fixedSize()` just before the `.frame(height: 100)`.

Comment: Option 1: LineLimit(2) has no affect on the app. But it breaks the widgets. The widgets now only have a single line and very small text.

Option 2: I added             .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
because just fixedSize made it one line overflowing out of the screen.
Now the text is shown in full on device and simulator. But i grows in vertical size and overflows the container.

Comment: Some interessting finding: When I add a .font() with a different font size to the MetarText block it updates the text size on the preview of xcode. But no at all on the device. seems like font changes have no effect on this

Comment: @Kurox: try adding `.allowsTightening()` before `.minimumScaleFactor(0.01)`

Comment: @Bafforasta: Thanks but sadly no change. Still everything is truncated